# WaitForSelector doesn't work when I entered some text in input field and press enter key in Puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I am going to simulate the typing and punch enter button.

I have typed some texts in the input field.

```
await page.waitForSelector("#selector");
await page.evaluate((arg) => {
    return document.querySelector("#selector").value = arg
}, "sample")
```

Then press the "enter" button.

```
await page.focus("#enter_btn")
await page.keyboard.press("Enter");
```

It is going to some search result and I need to wait for that. So...

```
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
await page.waitForSelector("#search-result")
```

But it shows time exceed error which means there is no node with that selector. (Which is on that page certainly).

What is the reason and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Please share the page you're working with. Does pressing Enter trigger navigation? There's no way to help without knowing how the page behaves since every website is different. It could be anything from `#search-result` never existing, an iframe issue, to a navigation issue. Please see [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Also: have you checked that the page is loaded as expected and the bot was not blocked? Can you run this script headfully and see what happens?